# handle an empty array parameter from the UI request

Tags: node.js, api

i am trying to accept array parameters from the frontend through swagger and do some function over as shown where i have sent a value in ingredient and no value in applicant

```
let applicant = req.swagger.params.applicant.value;
console.log(applicant);
console.log(typeof applicant);

let ingredient = req.swagger.params.ingredient.value;
console.log(ingredient);
console.log(typeof ingredient);
```

the following gets logged

```
[ '' ]
object
['somevalue']
object
```

i want to create a function such that

```
if (applicant && applicant !== ['']){
//do something
}
if (ingredient  && ingredient !== ['']){
// do something
}
```

but this doesn't seem to work. is there any other way to go around this

Comment: You can use `ingredient && ingredient.length && ingredient[0] !== ""`

Comment: thanks...that was helpful : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem with your approach is that is doesnt consider for the array to have an empty string. when you check with `if(applicant){//do something}` you do not consider that the array might have an empty string but string nonetheless.
this is why you actually need to check for the array length to determine if it is empty or not and then check for the first element is an empty string or not.

so ur code would look something like:

```
if (applicant && applicant.length && applicant[0]!== ''){
//do something
}
```